# How can I link an image of a jCarousel to a certain link?

Tags: javascript

I would like to link the different images of my jCarousel to different specific links depending on the actual image.

Comment: What element of each image would the links be dependent on?

Answer (score 5):

I assume you're using [views](http://drupal.org/project/views) and [jCarousel](http://drupal.org/project/jcarousel) and Drupal 7.

On same content type that you have your image fields, add a new [link](http://drupal.org/project/link) field. Add this link field to your view but check the `Exclude from display` checkbox, set the Formatter to `URL, as plain text` and make sure the link field is before of your image field in order.

[image]

Edit your image field settings in the view and, under `Rewrite Results`, check `Output this field as link`. Scroll down to the replacement patterns and copy the pattern that references your link field. Put this pattern in the `Link Path` text box.

[image]