# Followed the How can I link an image of a jCarousel to a certain link? page but need further help

Tags: entities

I followed the instructions on linking hyperlinks in jcarousel found here:
[How can I link an image of a jCarousel to a certain link?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9962/how-can-i-link-an-image-of-a-jcarousel-to-a-certain-link)

The problem is that I don't have the Formatter drop down field in my view.

Attached is a screenshot of what I see.

[image: Configure Field: Content: Link]

These are the choice I have when adding a link to the view. It appears to be the same link as what is in the original instruction:
[image: Link Choices]

Comment: I doubt the 'link' field you are adding the views here is a Drupal link field type. please recheck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field 'link' you have added is configured as a simple `Text` field from Content type field manager.

You need to choose Field Type as `'Link'` while creating it. Then only you can find those options in views.

My suggestion would be to create a new field 'link' and add it to views.

Let me know if you still find issues. :)

Comment: Hi Jeet, Thanks for you time in answering my question. As I am new to this, I imagine where you are referring to is under: Home » Administration » Structure » Content types » JCarousel (in my case) Then create a new field called Link, then make the field type Link? If this is the case, I don't have that option. I can see a range of choices, but nothing with the word link in it.

Comment: Further to my last, I imagine I need the module: https://drupal.org/project/link to get that functionality.

Comment: Yes, please. I forgot to mention . :)

Comment: Glad, I could help. :)